# Why has my simple CSS Z-index stopped working?

Tags: html, css

My page has elements class .fixed with a z-index of 1 and a #container with a z-index of 2, and this worked correctly until recently when they appear to have reversed. I can't figure out what change to the code has caused this. Can you take a look?

http://www.bewe.me/

The text is .fixed and the photos are in the #container. For me the photos scroll underneath the text instead of over it like they should. I've only tried on Chrome, though.

Comment: How about you post the relevant markup and code for us to see.

Answer (score 3):

Give your `#container` element a `position: relative;` and your problem should go away. You may also find this [expository piece](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/) on `z-index` helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Something with a `position:fixed` selector will be above a `position:static` (the default) block element. The fix for this case, would be to make the div id container relatively positioned. (`#container { position:relative; }`)